# How can I see the validation error returned from the rest api on kotlin?

Tags: java, android, spring, kotlin, retrofit

I have a spring based rest api.Checking my dto class for errors

ErrorDetails.java

```
public class ErrorDetails {
public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
    super();
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
}
public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}
private Date timestamp;
private String message;
private String details;


 }
```

GlobalExceptionHandler.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {


@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> customValidationErrorHanding(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception){
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), "Validation Error!",
            exception.getBindingResult().getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}


}
```

CustomerDto.java

```
public class CustomerDto {

private String nickName;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2 , max = 20 , message = "Incorret name")
private String name;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2 , max = 20 , message = "Incorret surname")
private String surname;

@NotBlank
@Email
private String e_mail;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 6, max = 20, message = "Your password should be at least 6 character")
private String password;

@NotNull
private long balance;

@Nullable
private long carID;

  //getter and setter method...

 }
```

CustomerController.java

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {


@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;



@PostMapping("/addcustomer")
public Customer addCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerDto customer) {
    return customerService.save(customer);        
}
}
```

CustomerServiceImpl.java

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService{

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;




@Override
public Customer save(CustomerDto customerdto){
    try {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        convertToEntity(customer, customerdto);

        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
    
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    
    
}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer,String>{
}
```

For example, when I test it in the postman app, I get the error correctly when the customer password is less than 6 digits.

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-01-04T20:32:40.665+00:00",
"message": "Validation Error!",
"details": "Your password should be at least 6 character"
}
```

I'm connecting from kotlin to spring with retrofit. For example, when I post a customer whose password is less than 6 digits, How can I see the details message in kotlin

This is how I do customer post in kotlin

```
        val test= Customer("aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaa@gmail.com","1",1111)

    val req= serviceNew.addCustomer(test)

    req.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
            println(t.message)
            println("fail")
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                println(response.body())
            }
            else
            {
                //println(????)
            }

        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get response message or code using methods `response.message()`, `response.code()` or `response.errorBody()`. Here is the documentation for Retrofit response: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html

In your case you can get the raw error body string by using `response.errorBody().string()` and then convert this string to JSONObject and get the details by using `.getString("details")` method.